# CListView statistic summary of array

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to create a summary of my array before my ClistView. Something that look like this

```
Total Cost: 5,000
Top Comment ID: 5456
Top State: AZ
```

is there way to do this using ClistVIew?

My array looks like this

```
[_new:Comment:private] => [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [id] => 6 [message] => dfgdgdghg ffgjfjfj [userId] => 5456 [createDate] => 2014-08-06 10:59:19 [cost] => 200 [state] => UT )
```

and my CListView

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$data,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'emptyText' => '<div class="alert alert-info">nothing found</div>',
    'summaryText' => '{count} posts'
));
```

currently for testing my `_view.php` looks like this

```
<div><?php echo $data->id.' '.$data->createDate.' '.$data->cost.' '.$data->state; ?></div>
```

i could just query my `comment` table and display a summary before the ClistView, was wondering if there was a better way or if i could do this in ClistView.

i would like the Clistview to display the results like this

```
------------------------------
|                            |
|  table summary             |
------------------------------
------------------------------
|                            |
| table                      |
------------------------------
```

Comment: your question is a bit confusing, but I guess [tempalte property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/clistview#template-detail) can help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You could derive your own class from CListView. In your derived class you can print the summary before handing over to CListView for printing out the rest. It makes sense to do this if your derived class with summary will be potentially useful to many views across models.

Comment: yes, i have 2 models that will use this. can i get a short example, maybe just for total cost? kind of new to yii